# Understanding the objcopy command in a book

Tags: elf

I am reading a [book](https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/pocorgtfo00.pdf) and it's talking about ELF's. I understand it's a file format for executable files.
There's a command that I executed on a VM and I'm having trouble understanding what it does.

```
objcopy -O binary -j .interp /bin/ls /dev/stdout
```

I opened the `/dev/stdout` file after executing and it just looks like a log information of some sort.

Comment: How did you open `/dev/stdout` ?

Comment: On the parrot os vm I’m running I opened the file with The Pluma text editor

Comment: Run 'man objdump'

Comment: When I run the command, I see `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2[alan@alan-laptop ~]$`. This means the ELF interpreter is `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.  Normally /dev/stdout should be a "special" file that writes the output e.g. to your terminal. It almost sounds as if your /dev/stdout was accidentally created as a regular file -  by some previous program.  AND, the /dev/stdout file was created by a different user like "root", so you did not have permission to overwrite the existing file at /dev/stdout with the contents `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

Comment: In this case, objdump should have printed an error message. On my system, the error message looks like `objcopy:/dev/stdout: Permission denied`.

Comment: I am voting to close / put this question on hold, because the question does not include enough information to confirm this.  I would vote to re-open if I saw you edit the question, and it showed an objdump error message. If you do not see an objdump error message, please run `ls -l /dev/stdout` instead. This will show if /dev/stdout is what it is supposed to be, or a regular file, or if it is something else entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Unix & Linux SE!

An ELF file has a binary header or two, and a number of named sections. [Wikipedia has a description of the structure of an ELF file, if you're interested.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)

Your `objcopy -O binary -j .interp /bin/ls /dev/stdout` command just outputs the contents of the `.interp` section of file `/bin/ls` exactly as-is (`-O binary`) to "file" `/dev/stdout`.

`/dev/stdout` should be a symbolic link to the current process's file descriptor #1, i.e. its standard output stream. It's basically just a way to tell a program that expects to write its output to a named file to use the standard output instead. Some programs can do that if you specify the output filename as just `-`, but apparently `objcopy` does not follow that convention.

If you're seeing "some sort of log information" when opening `/dev/stdout`, it might mean this symbolic link has been accidentally replaced by some program or script that has been run as root. It should look like this:

```
$ ls -l /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov 17 23:25 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
```

On a 64-bit x86 system, your `objcopy` command should output something like `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Since the output does not include a line-feed character at the end, it might appear on the same line as the next command prompt, making it harder to spot:

```
[my command prompt]$ objcopy -O binary -j .interp /bin/ls /dev/stdout
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2[my command prompt]$
```

On a 32-bit x86 binary, the output would be something like `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`.

The output is the filename of the *program interpreter* aka the *dynamic linker/loader* that should be used with the examined binary. You can get more information about it using the `man ld.so` or `man ld-linux` commands on your system.